# Get Wordpress ACF Taxomony and add to category

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I am using ACF to get the taxonomy, How to I get $place (which is the selected taxonomy) and add it to the installgallery_places post query? My code is:

`<?php
    $place = get_field('choose_place', 'installgallery_places');
    $args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'installgallery',
    'installgallery_places'=> '$place'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it like that

```
 $args = array( 
    'post_type'=> 'installgallery', 
    'meta_query' => array(
                      array(
                        'key' => 'installgallery_places',
                         'value' => $place,
                         )
                    )


  );
```

Maybe it could work with you original code if you remove the single quotes around the variable `$place`

Answer (score 0):

Worked this one out from trial and error, had to change the ACF taxonomy to 'Term Object' in the Return Value and used the following code to return the slug:

```
<?php
$variable = get_field('choose_place');
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'installgallery',
'installgallery_places' => $variable->slug
);              
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thanks for your help on this one